# Laravel SAML - user automatically logged out after log in

Tags: laravel, saml-2.0

I have connected my Laravel app to the Azure, and I'm using the SAML2 protocol for user authentication. The issue which i have is that user is logged in application (`Auth::login($user)`), and after that when printing `auth()->user()` i get logged in user object. However, somehow user session is destroyed after that, and the user is redirected to the login page. Callback for SAML response is located in a service provider `boot()` method and looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (Saml2LoginEvent $event) {
        $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
        // Add your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks

        $user = $event->getSaml2User();

        $userMap = config('saml2_settings.user_map');

        $emailAddress = $user->getAttribute($userMap['email']);
        $laravelUser = User::where('email', '=', $emailAddress[0])->first();

        if ($laravelUser) {
            Auth::login($laravelUser);
            return;
        }

        $azureService = new AzureService();
        $newUser = $azureService->createNewUserFromSaml($userMap, $user);

        if ($newUser){
            Auth::login($newUser);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Anybody can help?

Comment: In my case issue was with cookies SameSite flag - it was set to 'strict' and after changing it to 'lax', everything worked.